# How can I execute this math operation in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to do this operation:

```
$math = 1.30644 - 1.3063
```

I want the result to be the difference in this way:

1.4 (Which is 64,4 - 63) because I am dealing with PIPS. How can I achieve this result.

What I tried:

```
$math = 1.30644 - 1.3063

echo $math; // output -0.3063 I want it to output 1.4
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `1.30644 - 1.3063 = 0.00014000000000003`

Comment: Multiply your inputs by 10000?

Comment: Judging off your comments in some of the answers, you are looking to do some different computation based on the number of decimal places in the result. This is ok but you need to provide more examples (at least 3 preferably), there is no way to extrapolate that based on the single example you provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do exactly what you want:

```
$math = 1.30644 - 1.3063;
while ($math < 1) {
    $math *= 10;
}
var_dump($math);
//float(1.4000000000003)
```

You could round the result with the `round` function.

It works with any number:

```
$math = 64.4 - 63;
while ($math < 1) {
    $math *= 10;
}
var_dump($math);
//float(1.4)
```

Comment: And if the result is higher than 1? Would this not give an incorrect thought about the difference depending on the size of the numbers? The difference between 10 and 9 should not be 1 as well in this concept.

Comment: @Jonast92 In the case of `100 - 63`, the `$math` array would be `37`, which I *assume* is correct.

Comment: The author's question is quite unclear but my guess is that all results should be in the same base system, because now you can get 37 as a difference by putting in 2 different numbers where one is smaller than 1 and one is way larger than 1, which should not result in the same difference.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just multiply the output by 10000?

```
echo (1.30644 - 1.3063) * 10000;
```

Comment: What if I had no idea about the number of decimal points (how can I make it dynamic ? )

Comment: @user2344630 what do you mean? You want to round to a different number of decimal places? Or a fixed number of decimal places?

Comment: I want to be able to execute this 60.43 - 60.47 and this 1.4232 - 1.4212 all using same code (i have no idea about number of digits after the dot.)

Comment: @user2344630 So what is the answer to each of those subtractions since it's clearly not an actual subtraction you are doing

Comment: Number of dots doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to make it easy for you:

```
function diff($a, $b)
{
    return round(($a - $b) * 10000, 2);
}

$diff = diff(1.30644, 1.3063);
echo $diff; //Output: 1.4
```

Note that PHP is loosely types so it doesn't matter if you use an int or a double number.

If you would do

```
diff(60.430, 60.470)
```

Then you would get -400, which is correct if you want all numbers to be in base 10.000. The number of dots doesn't matter.

If you want better answers then you must improve your question.

Comment: What if the nubmer has different number of digits after the dot (e.g. 42.12 not 1.3322 isnt there a code that can be used in all cases?

Comment: That doesn't matter. The round function doesn't say WHAT can come into the function but HOW the result looks like. diff(60.43, 60.47) would result in -400 which is the differnce, resulting in a negative number, based on the result being in baser 10.000.

Answer (score 0):

```
$math = round((1.30644 - 1.3063) * 10000,2);
echo $math //1.4
```

Comment: What if I had no idea about the number of decimal points (how can I make it dynamic ? )

Comment: PHP is loosely typed so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$a = 1.30644;
$b = 1.3063;
$c = $a-$b;
echo $c;
```

Or if you want to remove three zeros from right use

```
echo $c*10000;
```

you may do it directly using

```
$a= (1.30644-1.3063)*10000;
echo $a;
```

Comment: No if you multiply it by 1000 you'l get : 0.14 else 0.00014

Comment: He doesn't want 0.14, he wants 1.14